# How does a program run on its on indefinitely

Tags: python

say I have a python program that uploads a photo on Instagram. If I wished to use that program every day,
is there another way of doing so, other then the following (trivial) options?:

1. run it on your own every day (for ex. with an IDE)
2. set a timer that performs the operation daily, and run the program with a while(true) loop

the Instagram example is simply for the purpose of the discussion

Comment: OSes have task schedulers that allow timed program runs - which OS are you using.

Comment: If you are on linux you could use a cron job. In windows you have a task scheduler you can use for this.

Comment: What is your os? You need scheduling in windows or crontab in linux. Also yiu script need run in commandline not ide

Comment: im using windows